# EVEE RELEASE DATE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When Evee is gonna be released? At least on beta? I watched the planning update video, and the Blender Core Developer said that the beta will be released at the of October, but now it's November and there is not. What happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site. Forgive me

Comment: EVEE is part of 2.80, a beta release is expected in the next few weeks with the aim of [releasing a stable version early next year.](https://code.blender.org/2018/10/blender-2-8-beta-and-roadmap/)

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's still in development stage, you can download it here https://builder.blender.org/download/ in the experimental builds, it's nowhere stable as 2.79, but you can test the new features

Comment: When the beta is going to be released?

Comment: In several weeks.